# React Native How Do I keep the user Loged in when he close the app

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

I am trying to save the user data when he loged in like this.

```
  const handleLogin = () => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, passWord)
      .then((res) => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userData) => {
          setuserData(userData);
          const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(userData);
          AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", jsonValue);
          console.log(userData);
        });
      })
      .then(() => navigation.navigate("HomeScreen"))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
```

and in the Spalch I am trying to check if the userData is in local storage or not .the problem is that it goes directly to HomeScreen even if there is No Data in Local storage
any help please

```
const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAnimating(true);
      navigation.replace(AsyncStorage.getItem("userData") ? "HomeScreen" : "Log_In");
    }, 500);
  }, 

[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage.getItem` returns promise so either you need to write it with async/await or in promise

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async() => {
      setAnimating(true);
      const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData")
      navigation.replace(user ? "HomeScreen" : "Log_In");
    }, 500);
  }, 
[]);
```

Comment: it gives an error of Unexpected reserved word "await'

Comment: You might missed to add async before callback function, check the code I have given

Comment: when I add this one it gives an error of  useEffect(() => {
    if (redirect) {
      setAnimating(true);
      navigation.replace(redirect);
    }
  }, [redirect]);
}; it gives me an error of  'return' outside of function. (36:2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this, a bit long but you can try it out

```
const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [animating, setAnimating] = useState();
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState('');

  const getUserData = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
    setRedirect(response ? 'HomeScreen' : 'Log_In');
  },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      getUserData();
    }, 500);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (redirect) {
      setAnimating(true);
      navigation.replace(redirect);
    }
  }, [redirect]);
};
```